# how to make a multi-task deep neural network baseline using huggingface transformers?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I was trying to build a [multi-task deep neural network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05098) using [xlm roberta large model](https://huggingface.co/jplu/tf-xlm-roberta-large) for a multilingual classification problem. my training dataset contains 4 columns :

1. ID
2. comment_text (according to id number,each users english comment is stored in this column. example comment : "you are a loser")
3. toxic (this column contains 1/0,0 means not toxic,1 means toxic)
4. personal_attack(this column also contains 0/1,,0 means the comment is not a personal attack type comment and 1 means opposite)

here is my models code :

```
def build_model(transformer, max_len=512):
    input_word_ids = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    sequence_output = transformer(input_word_ids)[0]
    cls_token = sequence_output[:, 0, :]
    out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name = 'y_train')(cls_token)
    out1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name = 'y_aux')(cls_token)
    model = Model(inputs=input_word_ids, outputs=[out, out1])
    model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-5), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

here is the code for train and test dataset :

```
train_dataset = (
tf.data.Dataset
.from_tensor_slices((x_train,

{ 'y_train':train.toxic.values,
'y_aux':train.identity_attack.values}

))
.repeat()
.shuffle(2048)
.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
.prefetch(AUTO)
)

test_dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset
    .from_tensor_slices(x_test)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
)
```

then for training model i used this code :

```
EPOCHS = 3
n_steps = x_train.shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE
train_history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=n_steps,
    epochs=EPOCHS
)
```

i don't wish to perform validation so just train_dataset was given for model.fit()

after 3 epoch i get performance like this :

```
Epoch 3/3
1658/1658 [==============================] - 887s 535ms/step - loss: 0.0591 - y_train_loss: 0.0175 - y_aux_loss: 0.0416 - y_train_accuracy: 0.9940 - y_aux_accuracy: 0.9821
```

now in my test set i have 1 columns :

1. comments( this column contains comments of non english language (remember in train set we only had English comments and here in test set all comments are non english)

so i expect my model to predict on these test set whether the given test set comment is toxic or not?
as you can see from 3rd epoch result that i am calculating y_train_accuracy: 0.9940 - y_aux_accuracy: 0.9821

now i want my model to predict y_test or toxic/not toxic only

for that i tried :

```
sub['toxic'] = model.predict(test_dataset, verbose=1)
```

sub is a dataframe that contains all the id of test set and using **test_dataset** i was trying to predict each and every test set comments but i get this error :

```
499/499 [==============================] - 126s 253ms/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1dc84858379e> in <module>
----> 1 sub['toxic'] = model.predict(test_dataset, verbose=1)
      2 sub.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2936         else:
   2937             # set column
-> 2938             self._set_item(key, value)
   2939 
   2940     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2998 
   2999         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3000         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3001         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3002 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3634 
   3635             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3636             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3637             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3638                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    609 
    610     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 611         raise ValueError("Length of values does not match length of index")
    612 
    613     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

now i have 4 questions :

1. is my implementation correct?
2. why i am getting that error? if i treat this problem as simple multilingual classification task like compute 1 loss for y true then i get no error at all,so where i am having trouble?
3. how can i solve the issue?
4. as it is my first time with multi task learning using huggingface transformers,what are your suggestions for updating my model so that it can generalize better?